# UWP Mqtt Connection

Tags: windows, mqtt, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I'm a beginner in C# programming. I want to develop an uwp app that will connect a mqtt server and it will read mqtt messages. It will run on windows 10 iot. Sources are so limited.Can anyone help me about that ?

Comment: Hello, StackOverflow works best when you ask a specific technical question (usually with accompanying code that shows the problem). General requests for tutorials on how to do things are frowned upon. Please read the guide to asking good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can add a MQTT client library from Nuget or internet as reference to the UWP project. Please note the library should support related .net standard version. Please refer to this [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) which lists the minimum platform versions that support each .NET Standard version.In addition, you need to add the [capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations)(internetClient ,privateNetworkClientServer) to the app so that the app can receive incoming data from internet or LAN.

I have tested with GnatMQ and [DotNetty](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty) MQTT library on 16299. The libraries work fine.

Comment: I'll try. Thank you.